# PHP simpleXMLelment xpath returns unexpected results

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have executed the following code on the the sample XML at the bottom of the question and I am getting unexpected results.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$addresses = $xml->response->addressinformation;
var_dump($addresses->xpath('//record'));
```

I would expect this to return only the two `record` nodes that are children of the current `addresses` node.  But, it actually returns all 5 of the `record` nodes of the original `$xml` element.  Everything I have read says that the `//` notation is relative to the current node.  I realize that there are other ways to get to just the two records I've referenced in the questions. `$addresses->xpath('records/record');` is just one example.  But, the strange behavior is part of a larger problem I'm having and I just need to understand why it is behaving this way. Everything I've read would lead me to believe otherwise.  Can anyone help me understand?

Sample XML

```
$xml_string = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <response>
        <addressinformation>
            <records>
                <record id="1">
                    <fullname>JOHN E DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                    <middlename>E</middlename>
                    <lastname>DOE</lastname>
                    <fulldob>01/01/1970</fulldob>
                </record>
                <record id="2">
                    <fullname>JOHN E DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                </record>
            </records>
        </addressinformation>
        <otherinformation>
            <records>
                <record id="3">
                    <fullname>JOHN DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                    <lastname>DOE</lastname>
                    <fulldob>01/01/1970</fulldob>
                </record>
                <record id="4">
                    <fullname>JOHN EDWARD DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                    <middlename>EDWARD</middlename>
                    <lastname>DOE</lastname>
                    <fulldob>19700000</fulldob>
                </record>
                <record id="5">
                    <fullname>JOHN EDWARD DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                    <middlename>EDWARD</middlename>
                    <lastname>DOE</lastname>
                    <fulldob>19830000</fulldob>
                </record>
            </records>
        </otherinformation>
    </response>
</root>
';
```

Comment: I've been looking around but cannot find anything in SimpleXML docs that would make `//` relative to the selected node rather than the full document. I would expect you'd get the same doc-level behavior if you queried `$addresses->xpath('/records')`, no results because that path doesn't exist at the root

Comment: This might be an area where SimpleXML's object-oriented traversal API sort of collides with standard xpath syntax against expectations. I don't think your expectation/interpretation was unreasonable, but that is not how it is intended to work as far as documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/:

> `//para` selects all the para descendants of the document root and thus selects all para elements in the same document as the context node

and

> `.//para` selects the para element descendants of the context node

Note the dot before the latter one. This also works in your case:

```php
var_dump($addresses->xpath('.//record'));
```

properly only shows the two nodes you are expecting.

The thing is - apparently - that even all the objects are just of type `SimpleXMLElement`, the first one that you are creating by calling `simplexml_load_string()` is for some reason considered the document root. When you "destruct" your document into nodes and subnodes this all makes sense to me.

**However** I would agree that this is at least some behaviour that is not documented in the PHP docs, so I recommend you suggest an edit there.

Comment: Thank you!  I spent hours reading what I could find and could not come up with the answer.  Now that you've spelled it out for me it has clarified some other issues I was having. Thanks for taking the time to help me resolve this!  I'll suggest the edit in the PHP docs.

Comment: My pleasure. More often than not in those situations its a good idea to look back again at the very basics. Good luck!

Comment: After you told me what to look for the answer was actually given to me in some of the resources I had already searched.  This for example https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php#101804.  It is just too easy to miss among all the other noise. Or maybe it has something to do with only searching for the information when you are tired and frustrated from trying to figure it out for hours beforehand:)